# Why doesn't VSCode show a * next to the active environment name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda

Here is my terminal output in Visual Studio Code.

```
PS D:\Python_Projects\idol-sentiment-analysis> C:/Users/Owner/miniconda3/Scripts/activate
PS D:\Python_Projects\idol-sentiment-analysis> conda activate idol-sentiment-analysis
PS D:\Python_Projects\idol-sentiment-analysis> conda info --env
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3
idol-sentiment-analysis     C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3\envs\idol-sentiment-analysis
```

I tried typing `conda activate idol-sentiment-analysis`. Then I typed `conda info --env`. I expected to see

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3
idol-sentiment-analysis  *  C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3\envs\idol-sentiment-analysis
```

I expected to see the * after idol-sentiment-analysis because that is the environment I just activated. I also expected to see the * because other users of VSC see the * next to their activated environment.
Here is an image of another user that sees the *.
[visual studio code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T179b.png)
What actually happened was that I saw

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3
idol-sentiment-analysis     C:\Users\Owner\miniconda3\envs\idol-sentiment-analysis
```